# Smarty Uploading a File with normal Input Files

Tags: php, file-upload, input, smarty

In my index.php file , I got a code is trace the $_FILE, but seems like when uploaded a pic/jpeg/images file, the return result is 'array(0) { }'. Did I need use smarty's method to assign a input file's method?

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

my photoupload.tpl

```
<form action="index.php?view=photoupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <input class="btn_name" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you dont have to, heres a part of my current project where i work with smarty:

```
<form action="upload_contract.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

...

<div class="row">
    <div class="large-5 columns">
        <label for="upload">Dateiupload:</label><span><input type="file" id="upload" name="upload"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This one works fine without additional methods.